# Does Django Admin support an "Are you sure you want to do that" popup when a user is saving a new record?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an admin page that allows a user to make "usual" and and some "unusual" changes.

The "unusual" would be setting a field on the model to None. I could check for this in `ModelAdmin.save_model` but I'd like to check the user is happy with what they're doing. Is there a standard way of notifying the user that they're doing something a bit funky and checking whether or not they definitely want to proceed? Ideally without custom html and redirects.